# What JavaScript frameworks are out there for building smartphone websites?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, frame, mobile-website, smartphone

I'm looking to see what JavaScript Frameworks exist for the creation of Smartphone websites and what your experiences with them have been?

Similar to the work in progress jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/)

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Touch looks pretty solid from what I have seen.  It Has more than just cross device touch devices which is the bare minimum I would want when developing mobile apps.  It also has a UI framework (which I am guessing uses SVG since it claims to be resolution independent). It is created by the same people who made EXTJS so I would expect it to be a quality product. It might be worth a look:

http://www.sencha.com/

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll take sometime to site down and give it a once over.

Comment: [Sencha person] We don't use SVG for resolution independence, we do smart things with ems rather than pixels for sizing. See our recent blog on how we do some of this stuff

Comment: Wow, very interesting.  Here is a link for anyone else who is interested: http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/08/23/resolution-independent-mobile-ui/

Answer (score 0):

There are some jQuery plugins like http://jqtouch.com/ .

And yes, many of us are waiting for jQueryMobile :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside jQuerymobile, Sencha Touch and jQTouch there are no more frameworks which are suitable for mobile web applications. But I think in the next month, the other JavaScript frameworks like DoJo, YUI, etc. will also offer this support. But Sencha Touch is the best at the moment, because jQuerymobile is not released yet.

But I will wait for jQuerymobile.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a simple code and take advantage of innovative components, you should look at the javascript toolkit **[Wink](http://www.winktoolkit.org)**, a project of the Dojo Foundation.